# cannot call method from another controller in angularjs ionic framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to trigger/call the `callkhs` from `LihatKhsController` to `KhsController`:

```
function KhsController($scope, $rootScope){
     $scope.$emit('callkhs', {param:'test'});
}
```

and I try to get parameter from `KhsController` to `LihatController`:

```
function LihatKhsController($scope, $rootScope){
    $scope.$on("callkhs", function(event, data){
      console.log('halo callkhs', data.param); //not show
    });
}
```

please help me to solve this.

Comment: can u use Service..to call same function in both controller..!?

Answer (score 2):

If you use `$scope.$emit`, it'll notify only it's parent `scope`.

Like this

```
<div ng-contoller="LihatKhsController">
 <div ng-controller="KhsController">
 </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function KhsController($scope, $rootScope){
     $scope.$emit('callkhs', {param:'test'});
}
function LihatKhsController($scope, $rootScope){
    $scope.$on("callkhs", function(event, data){
      console.log('halo callkhs', data.param); //not show
    });
}
```

Here `KhsController` will trigger `LihatKhsController` as `LihatKhsController` is prent of `KhsController` .

If you use `$scope.$broadcast` , it'll notify it's child

Like this

```
<div ng-contoller="KhsController">
 <div ng-controller="LihatKhsController">
 </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function KhsController($scope, $rootScope){
     $scope.$emit('callkhs', {param:'test'});
}
function LihatKhsController($scope, $rootScope){
    $scope.$on("callkhs", function(event, data){
      console.log('halo callkhs', data.param); //not show
    });
}
```

Here `KhsController` will trigger `LihatKhsController` as `KhsController`  is parent of `LihatKhsController`.

Both of them won't consider siblings controller Like

```
<div ng-contoller="KhsController">
</div>
 <div ng-controller="LihatKhsController">
 </div>
```

`$emit` and `$broadcast` is slightly different in `rootScope`.

If you use `$rootScope.$emit`, it'll  only notify on `$rootScope.$on`.

If you use `$rootScope.$broadcast`,it'll not only notify on  `$rootScope.$on` but also all `$scope.$on`.

Like this

```
function KhsController($scope, $rootScope){
     $rootScope.$broadcast('callkhs', {param:'test'});
}

function LihatKhsController($scope, $rootScope){
    $scope.$on("callkhs", function(event, data){
      console.log('halo callkhs', data.param);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [redux](https://github.com/rackt/redux)? It's a modern way to write applications that behave consistently. There is an [redux angular bindings](https://github.com/wbuchwalter/ng-redux).

Comment: Angular has such tools by default. Angular does not need Redux.

Comment: @AlexanderElgin This is wrong, redux is not a tool. You could use DI, `$broadcast`, `$scope` or anything to achieve this but @Anik is asking what's the best practice (the design pattern and maintainability of the code). redux is the modern way to do it.

Comment: In Angular the best practice is to not use Redux

Comment: Why? Redux is the reason why react is smashing everything else.

Comment: React is popular because of it performance. Redux is just a tool used by React. But it is not required in Angular.

Comment: As I said redux is a design pattern. Anything could use it. Using redux is more maintainable than any other patterns so far.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers that use `$rootScope.$broadcast` and the associated `$rootScope.$on` will work, but I prefer using `$rootScope.$emit` in this situation. Considering you are listening from `$rootScope`, it doesn't make since to propagate the message down the entire scope tree.  With `$rootScope.$emit` and `$rootScope.$on`, it's essentially a direct message.  The performance benefit might be negligible but I see no downside to this approach.

```js
var app = angular.module('khsApp', []);

app.controller("KhsController", function ($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.sendMessage = function() {
    $rootScope.$emit('message', 'message sent');
  }
});

app.controller("LihatKhsController", function ($scope, $rootScope) {
  $rootScope.$on("message", function($event, data) {
    $scope.received = data;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="khsApp">
  <form ng-controller="KhsController">
    <button ng-click="sendMessage()">Send</button>
  </form>
  <div ng-controller="LihatKhsController">
   <span ng-bind="received"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```